# Classifying Data in a New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following df:

```
Column 1
1
2435
3345
104
505
6005
10000
80000
100000
4000000
4440
520
...
```

This structure is not the best to plot a histogram, which is the main purpose. Bins don't really solve the problem either, at least from what I've tested so far. That's why I like to create my own bins in a new column:

I basically want to assign every value within a certain range in column 1 a bucket in column2, so that it look like this:

```
Column 1    Column2
1           < 10000
2435        < 10000
3345        < 10000  
104         < 10000
505         < 10000
6005        < 10000
10000       < 50000
80000       < 150000
100000      < 150000
4000000     < 250000
4440        < 10000
520         < 10000
...
```

Once I get there, creating a plot will be much easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pandas equivalent to this [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.cut.html#pandas.cut) there is a section describing this [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/basics.html?highlight=cut#discretization-and-quantiling). `cut` returns the open closed intervals for each value:

```
In [29]:    
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['Column 1'], bins = [0,10000, 50000, 150000, 25000000])
df

Out[29]:

    Column 1                 bin
0          1          (0, 10000]
1       2435          (0, 10000]
2       3345          (0, 10000]
3        104          (0, 10000]
4        505          (0, 10000]
5       6005          (0, 10000]
6      10000          (0, 10000]
7      80000     (50000, 150000]
8     100000     (50000, 150000]
9    4000000  (150000, 25000000]
10      4440          (0, 10000]
11       520          (0, 10000]
```

The dtype of the column is a [`Category`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/categorical.html) and can be used for filtering, counting, plotting etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) takes a `bins` parameter which can be an integer array, and returns an array of the counts within those bins. So, if you run

```
import numpy as np

counts, _ = np.histogram(df[`Column 1`].values, [10000, 50000, 150000, 250000])
```

You will have the bins you want. From here, you can do whatever you want, including plotting the number of counts within each bin:

```
plot(counts)
```

Comment: ``hist`` -> ``histogram`` (``hist`` is pyplot or something).

Comment: Whatever you want - ``plot(.)`` does line or dots. ``bar`` does bars. Once you're at this point, you should check the matplotlib gallery for what works for you. It's not a classical histogram in any case, at this point.

Comment: I know, the point is exactly that I will start at zero here. There is no really good way to bin the data it seems..